# Window.top.opener is null/undefined in the child window opened from gmail in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am getting **undefined** for window.top.opener value in the child window which is opened from Gmail main window, in IE browser.
Whereas in Mozilla, getting **null** value.

I am getting some value when I open child windows for other sites.
Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting undefined for window.top.opener value in the child window which is opened from Gmail main window, in IE browser. Whereas in Mozilla, getting null value.

GMail is most likely using the [`noopener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#noopener) option/setting in their `window.open` call, which has the explicit purpose of *not* allowing the page opened in the popup access to the opener.

> I am getting some value when I open child windows for other sites. Please help me to solve it.

There is no way to solve this, as this is deliberately set by GMail, to prevent any access from pages opened from within their webmail interface back to that webmail interface.

Comment: Hi, Actually we are getting the value of window.top.opener in the browsers for some machines. Here, we are using <a href = "SomeExmaple" target = "_blank" ></a>

Comment: @chitra _“Actually we are getting the value of window.top.opener in the browsers for some machines”_ - then those are most likely browser versions that do not have this option implemented yet …?

Comment: Hi, Actually we are getting the value of window.top.opener in the browsers of few machines. Here, they are not using window.opener for opening child window, instead used as below to open child window <a href = "SomeExmaple" target = "_blank" ></a>. Could you please help on this.